# Auction Closing Date MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, time, mean-stack

i'm building an auction site with the MEAN stack, for training. I have little problems to understand a thing. I stored a closing date in the format ""2017-04-30T22:10:52.360Z" for every product in the DB. On the front-end i show the difference between today's date and the closing date (something like "30 days remaining") with this function:

```
          $scope.days =function (date) {
           var today = new Date();
           var dd = today.getDate();
           var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
           var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
           if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd
            }
           if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm
              }
           today = yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;
           $scope.today = today;
           var date2 = new Date(today);
           var date1 = new Date(date);
           var timeDiff =(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
           $scope.dayDifference =((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24))-1);
            return $scope.dayDifference;
              }
           });
```

Obviously i pass the other date in the html file.
My question is:  if i do something like this, the auction closes on different times in the world, cause today's date (and time) is different in Italy and United States for example. Or am i wrong?
I know, momentjs, but i was wondering if exist a way to modify this function on the front-end with angular, to fix this bug. Something like: If i join the site from USA, it convert that date to my timezone (of the server)

Comment: What is the format of *date*? If it's an ISO 8601 string with timezone, e.g. "2017-04-30T22:10:52.360Z" then you can convert that to a "local" date using the built-in Date constructor in all browsers since IE 8 (and most before then). If it's some other format, it takes a little more work but not much.

Comment: `var date2 = new Date(today)` may return an invalid Date since you changed *today* from a Date to a string.

Comment: Hi @RobG. The date is in ISO form as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date string is in ISO 8601 extended format like "2017-04-30T22:10:52.360Z", then browsers newer than IE 8 can parse it with their built-in parser. Also, by default the Date methods adjust for the host timezone offset so to get the number of days remaining you can parse the ISO string and get the difference from the user's current date in milliseconds, then convert to days (or whatever units suit) e.g.

```js
/* Return the difference in days between supplied string date
** and host current date
** @param {string} s - Date string in ISO 8601 format, e.g. 2017-04-05T23:00:00Z
** @returns {number/string} if s is a valid date string, returns days between current host date and supplied date
**                          if s is an invalid date string, returns "Invalid date string"
*/
function daysRemaining(isoString) {
  var d = new Date(isoString);
  if (isNaN(d)) return 'Invalid date string';
  return (d - new Date()) / 8.64e7;
}

var s = '2017-05-30T22:10:52.360Z';

console.log('Days remaining: ' + daysRemaining(s).toFixed(2));
```

If the date string is not precisely ISO 8601 format, some browsers may parse it and others many not. Also, if not the above ISO format, some may treat it as UTC and some as local, so beware of that.

You may want to round to whole days, or convert to days, hours and minutes.

Note that IE 8 and earlier will not parse ISO format date strings, nor will older versions of some other browsers.